# React form validation error - Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Tags: reactjs, validation

I am trying to make a separate component which has field validation logic, because I know that I will use this on other forms, but I am receiving an error when trying to retrieve the state from the parent component, which has the login form

The following is the login form component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import '../css/login.scss';
import 'bootstrap';
import Validators from './services/Validators';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import FetchServices from './services/FetchServices';
import $ from 'jquery';

export class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state= {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            username: '',
            errorMsg: '',
            errors: {
                usernameError: "",
                emailError: "",
                passwordError: ""
            },
            isError: false,
            hasError: false,
            _remember_me: true,
            jwt: ''
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // console.log(React.version);
    }

    handleClick() {
        let notifications = $('#notifications');
        let url = '/login';
        let email = this.state.email;
        let pswd = this.state.password;
        let usrn = this.state.username;
        let remember = this.state._remember_me;
        FetchServices.getInstanceFetch().authService(url, email, pswd, usrn, remember);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container login-container">
                <div className="nofication-container">
                    <div id="notifications">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
                    <TextField
                        label="Username"
                        placeholder="Username"
                        name="username"
                        type="text"
                        helperText={this.state.errors.usernameError}
                        onChange = {(event) => this.setState({username:event.currentTarget.value})}
                        onBlur={(event) => {
                                this.setState({username:event.currentTarget.value});
                                Validators.getInstanceValidators().validateUsername();
                            }
                        }
                    />
                    <br />
                    <TextField
                        label="Email"
                        placeholder="email"
                        name="email"
                        type="email"
                        helperText={this.state.errors.emailError}
                        onChange = {(event) => this.setState({email:event.currentTarget.value})}
                        onBlur={(event) => {
                            this.setState({email:event.currentTarget.value});
                            Validators.getInstanceValidators().validateEmail();
                            }
                        }
                    />
                    <br />
                    <TextField
                        label="Password"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        name="password"
                        type="password"
                        helperText={this.state.errors.passwordError}
                        onChange = {(event) => this.setState({password:event.currentTarget.value})}
                        onBlur={(event) => {
                            this.setState({password:event.currentTarget.value});
                            Validators.getInstanceValidators().validatePassword();
                            }
                        }
                    />
                    <br />
                    <Button label="Login" variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)}>
                        Sign Up
                    </Button>
                </form>
                <br />
                <div className="checkbox mb-3 login-remember-me">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" defaultChecked
                               onChange = {(event) => this.setState({_remember_me:event.currentTarget.value})}
                        /> Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div className="checkbox mb-3 login-remember-me">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" defaultChecked
                        onChange={(event) => this.setState({_remember_me:event.currentTarget.value})}/> Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div className="btn-group">
                    <Button label="Cancel" color="secondary" onClick={() => window.location.href = "/"}>
                        Cancel
                    </Button>
                    <Button label="login" color="primary" onClick={() => window.location.href = "/support"}>
                        Forgot username
                    </Button>
                    <Button label="support" color="primary" onClick={() => window.location.href = "/support"}>
                        Forgot password
                    </Button>
                    <Button label="support" color="primary" onClick={() => window.location.href = "/sign-up"}>
                        Sign-up/Register
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDom.render(<Login />, document.getElementById('Login'));
```

The following is the Validator component:

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';

export class Validators extends Component{
    static getInstanceValidators() {
        return new Validators();
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(...props);
        this.state={
            errMsg: ''
        }
    }

    async validateUsername() {
        const regexSpecialChars = /^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+$/g;

        if (this.props.username.length == 0) {
            this.props.errors.usernameError = "Username is required";
        } else if (this.props.username.length < 8) {
            this.props.errors.usernameError = "Username must be longer than eight characters";
        } else if (this.props.username > 0 && (regexSpecialChars.test(this.props.username))) {
            console.log('makes it to past zero length');
            this.props.errors.usernameError = "Username cannot contain special characters - [ ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) + = { _ }";
        } else {
            this.props.errors.usernameError = "";
        }
    };

    async validateEmail() {
        const regexEmail = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

        if (this.props.email.length == 0) {
            this.props.errors.emailError = "Email is required";
        } else if (this.props.email.length > 0) {
            if (!regexEmail.test(this.props.email)) {
                this.props.errors.emailError = "Please enter a valid email";
            } else {
                this.props.errors.emailError = "";
            }
        } else {
            this.props.errors.usernameError = "";
        }
    };

    async validatePassword() {
        if (this.props.password.length == 0) {
            this.props.errors.passwordError = "Password is required";
        } else if (this.props.password.length < 8) {
            this.props.errors.passwordError = "Password must be longer than eight characters";
        } else {
            this.props.errors.passwordError = "";
        }
    };
}

export default Validators;
```

I have tried to do the following to inherit the props by using = () =>

```
validateUsername = () => {
        const regexSpecialChars = /^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+$/g;

        if (this.props.username.length == 0) {
            this.props.errors.usernameError = "Username is required";
        } else if (this.props.username.length < 8) {
            this.props.errors.usernameError = "Username must be longer than eight characters";
        } else if (this.props.username > 0 && (regexSpecialChars.test(this.props.username))) {
            console.log('makes it to past zero length');
            this.props.errors.usernameError = "Username cannot contain special characters - [ ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) + = { _ }";
        } else {
            this.props.errors.usernameError = "";
        }
    };
```

But then the server logs gives the following error:

```
Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel
```

I have tried to use the ...props without the super, but - missed superclass constructor classfication error

How do I pass this.state.username from the Login component to the Validation component?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to pass the props directly. With that said, I know there has to be a better way using props, but this solution works

The following is the parent login component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import '../css/login.scss';
import 'bootstrap';
import Validators from './services/Validators';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import FetchServices from './services/FetchServices';
import $ from 'jquery';

export class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state= {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            username: '',
            errorMsg: '',
            errors: {
                usernameError: "",
                emailError: "",
                passwordError: ""
            },
            hasError: false,
            _remember_me: true
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // console.log(React.version);
    }

    handleClick() {
        let notifications = $('#notifications');
        let url = '/login';
        let email = this.state.email;
        let pswd = this.state.password;
        let usrn = this.state.username;
        let remember = this.state._remember_me;
        FetchServices.getInstanceFetch().authService(url, email, pswd, usrn, remember);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container login-container">
                <div className="nofication-container">
                    <div id="notifications">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
                    <TextField
                        label="Username"
                        placeholder="Username"
                        name="username"
                        type="text"
                        helperText={this.state.errors.usernameError}
                        onChange = {(event) => this.setState({username:event.currentTarget.value})}
                        onBlur={(event) => {
                                this.setState({username:event.currentTarget.value});
                                Validators.getInstanceValidators().validateUsername(this.state.username, this.state.errors);
                            }
                        }
                    />
                    <br />
                    <TextField
                        label="Email"
                        placeholder="email"
                        name="email"
                        type="email"
                        helperText={this.state.errors.emailError}
                        onChange = {(event) => this.setState({email:event.currentTarget.value})}
                        onBlur={(event) => {
                            this.setState({email:event.currentTarget.value});
                            Validators.getInstanceValidators().validateEmail(this.state.email, this.state.errors);
                            }
                        }
                    />
                    <br />
                    <TextField
                        label="Password"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        name="password"
                        type="password"
                        helperText={this.state.errors.passwordError}
                        onChange = {(event) => this.setState({password:event.currentTarget.value})}
                        onBlur={(event) => {
                            this.setState({password:event.currentTarget.value});
                            Validators.getInstanceValidators().validatePassword(this.state.password, this.state.errors);
                            }
                        }
                    />
                    <br />
                    <Button label="Login" variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)}>
                        Login
                    </Button>
                </form>
                <br />
                <div className="checkbox mb-3 login-remember-me">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" defaultChecked
                               onChange = {(event) => this.setState({_remember_me:event.currentTarget.value})}
                        /> Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div className="checkbox mb-3 login-remember-me">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" defaultChecked
                        onChange={(event) => this.setState({_remember_me:event.currentTarget.value})}/> Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div className="btn-group">
                    <Button label="Cancel" color="secondary" onClick={() => window.location.href = "/"}>
                        Cancel
                    </Button>
                    <Button label="login" color="primary" onClick={() => window.location.href = "/support"}>
                        Forgot username
                    </Button>
                    <Button label="support" color="primary" onClick={() => window.location.href = "/support"}>
                        Forgot password
                    </Button>
                    <Button label="support" color="primary" onClick={() => window.location.href = "/sign-up"}>
                        Sign-up/Register
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDom.render(<Login />, document.getElementById('Login'));
```

The following is the child validators component, which is now available for the signup component or any other component that needs a username, email or password validator. Hooking it up to the signup component took less than half a minute:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export class Validators extends Component{
    static getInstanceValidators() {
        return new Validators();
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            errMsg: ''
        }
    }

    async validateUsername(username, errors) {
        const regexSpecialChars = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]/g;

        if (username.length == 0) {
            errors.usernameError = "Username is required";
        } else if (username.length < 8) {
            errors.usernameError = "Username must be longer than eight characters";
        } else if (username.length > 0 && (regexSpecialChars.test(username))) {
            console.log('makes it to past zero length');
            errors.usernameError = "";
        } else {
            errors.usernameError = "Username cannot contain special characters - [ ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) + = { _ }";
        }
    };

    async validateEmail(email, errors) {
        const regexEmail = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

        if (email.length == 0) {
            errors.emailError = "Email is required";
        } else if (email.length > 0) {
            if (!regexEmail.test(email)) {
                errors.emailError = "Please enter a valid email";
            } else {
                errors.emailError = "";
            }
        } else {
            errors.usernameError = "";
        }
    };

    async validatePassword(password, errors) {
        if (password.length == 0) {
            errors.passwordError = "Password is required";
        } else if (password.length < 8) {
            errors.passwordError = "Password must be longer than eight characters";
        } else {
            errors.passwordError = "";
        }
    };
}

export default Validators;
```

With this working, I would still love to understand how to have this working by using "...props" instead of the following:

```
Validators.getInstanceValidators().validateUsername(this.state.username, this.state.errors);
```